# Assests in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have the following file structure in Codeigniter:

```
application
system
assets
-- js
-- imgs
-- css
```

From what I've read inorder to link correctly to these asset files I should make a helper like so:

```
function asset_url(){
   return base_url().'assets/';
}
```

I'm completely new to Codeigniter and MVC architecture. Please could someone explain how I achieve this.

Do I create a new file in the application/helpers folder called "asset_helper.php" then put the code above in?

Then what do I write in my html to link to say a css file in my assets folder?

Comment: Define **assets** in your .htaccess, then it will work
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|assets|.ico)

Comment: creating helper is not necessary for this. @tomexsans has already answered how you can acheve this in a simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as described in [helpers guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html) (and in your question), you place you functions in a file under `application/helpers/` ending with `_helper.php` in the file name. Once you have that in place you will have to load it with

```
$this->load->helper('asset');
```

Or with the autoload config under `application/config/autoload.php`.

You might want to warp your individual functions inside the `_helper.php` file with an if like this:

```
if ( ! function_exists('asset_url')) {
    function asset_url() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So in case of name collision you won't have fatal errors. I would argue that it's better to know if there's a collision, but CI's own helper files do this for so you can define one or two helpers of your own with the colliding names while leaving others intact from the same helper file.

Answer (score 1):

A simple

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url('assets/css');?>" type="text/css">
```

will do the trick.

But if you want to follow it, you could put the function directly on the core `uri_helper` found on `system/helpers/url_helper` or create a new helper on the `application/helper` directory, note that you must name your file with a `_helper` at the end, example
`filename_of_myhelper_helper`, then you can load it as `$this->load->helper('filename_of_myhelper')`, also keep in mind that the differences on `helper` and `library` is that a `library` is a class while a `helper` is just a php file with assorted functions.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use

```
$cssFooPath = $this->config->base_url() . 'css/foo.css';
```

this way codeigniter handles the base url (gives you absolute paths in the html file and I place the assets dir in the root of the app just like you do. 
The same would go for 'js/foo.js' or 'img/foo.png' obviously.

With this .htaccess if you're using apache

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|assets|hg)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

makes it easy to give http headers when the files haven't changed because apache will handle all of that